# Weird characters appearing and page not loading when trying to access object property

Tags: php, object

I have created a class in a php file in the following way:

```
class thingy {
    ...
    var $property;
    ...
}
```

Once the class is created (in a separate file which I'm including) I do the following:

```
$mything = new thingy();

$mything->$property = 5;
```

(this is an example with modified var and property names, but it's the same code except those names, and the fact that I'm only showing one property here.)

I get the following output when displaying the page, and it's not loading anymore (the header and footer are not showing, just a weird output).

I get something like this whenever I load the page:

```
‹$A Ã0ï}…^ÐÐKÁøè+t‘ †D²ŠéïÓÓ³›ŠÃ’©ä7Àîêi)yØID¨Vîø²ø‚¹û Mà–ö ]†c$³Þ‚g"Õh*•>q<í°9 *p6á)¾ÖuVéÿÿÿ»-¶†
```

When I remove the line where I'm trying to set a property, my page loads alright. I'm stuck.

Comment: Check your editor for weird characters in the file. setting a variable should not display any characters to the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$mything->property = 5;
```

You don't need the second '$'.  That is trying to set a variable whose name is the **value** of $property.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed a dumb syntax error. I'm beginner in object PHP, so that isn't very surprising. I'll choose your answer as soon as the 15 minutes delay is over. :)

Comment: No problem, we've all been there.  I'm not sure what you're using. but as a beginner, I would suggest switching to a more advanced IDE like Eclipse or PHPStorm, though.  They catch errors like this easily and highlight them so you don't end up banging your head against the wall.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using Aptana, which is apparently made quite like Eclipse, but more web-oriented. Yet it didn't tell me anything about this error, so yeah, maybe I should switch.

Comment: Well you may just need to change some settings, I'm not familiar with Aptana.  A lot of beginner tutorials say things like "you can create a php file with any text editor, like Notepad."  You can, but it's a pretty masochistic thing to do to yourself.  I just wanted to make sure you were using an actual IDE.